# What would happen if Newton's Cradle was made of other geometrical objects rather than spheres?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

What would happen if [Newton's Cradle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle) was made of other geometrical objects rather than spheres?
For example, what would happen if it was made of cubes and the contact area was larger?

Comment: I don't see any reason why increasing the surface area of interaction has to decrease the elasticity of the collision.

Comment: I could see making them cubes would increase the chance that spurious motion parallel to the direction of the surface could cause energy loss due to friction.

Comment: Sphere do not rotate when impacted, but other shapes do. So instead of transferring linear velocity from one object to the next it will induce rotations.

Answer (score 1):

In ideal conditions, if the geometrical objects are such that when they collide the collision doesn't generate rotation of the objects, then Newton's Cradle shouldn't be different. The bodies will exchange momentum just as the spheres do. Notice that contact area doesn't matter if you think of the collision as an interaction between point-like particles. If you consider geometrical objects that collide in such a way that they rotate, then momentum wouldn't be exchanged in a similar way as spheres do (or cubes would do as well).

Comment: Cubes are hard to make "ideal" collisions with, in practice objects will be sent spinning and tumbling, causing the whole system to be damped down much more quickly.

Comment: It would be interested to see this with shapes with two possible impact points each. One being a pivot point and the other the corresponding percussion point. This is achieved if the distance to the center of mass equals the radius of gyration (like with hanging rings).